# How to retrieve the full url of the item

Tags: c#, javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am working with SharePoint 2010 and ECMAScript.

I have added a customaction to the context menu of a document inside a document library.

how is it possible to retrieve the full path url of the document using ecmascript?

i was trying something like this (but it fails if im in a subsite or site collection)

my custom action:

```
 <UrlAction Url="javascript:OpenDialog('Miopiaggo/shoot.aspx?id=' + '{SiteUrl}' + document.getElementById({ItemId}).firstChild.getAttribute('href'),'shooter');"/>
```

and my opendialog function is:

```
function OpenDialog(dialogPage,dialogTitle) {
    var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
    options.url = SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl(dialogPage);
    options.url += "?Source=" + document.URL;
    options.title = dialogTitle;
    options.dialogReturnValueCallback = Function.createDelegate(null, CloseCallback);
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}
```

The problem, the querystring that is supposed to get me the full path of the document url is not good, its messed up with duplicates when i am in a subsite or site collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the solution presented on Jan Tielens blog posting about [USING THE CURRENT PAGE URL IN THE URLACTION OF A SHAREPOINT FEATURE](http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2007/09/05/using-the-current-page-url-in-the-urlaction-of-a-sharepoint-feature.aspx).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, helpfull, the result is: we cannot get the document url like this, what we can do is get the ListId and the ItemId, and then by using the web, get the SPListitem object and from there get the url.